# Select Maximum number from a numeric field in an entity (Dynamics CRM 2016)

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals

What is the best way to retrieve the maximum value from a numeric field in an entity?  Something like this in SQL Server: `Select MAX(NumbericFieldName) From TableName`.

I tried this:

```
var documentno = XrmContext.CreateQuery("nychro_traportaldocumentupload").Max(c => c.GetAttributeValue<Int32?>("nychro_portaldocumentreviewid"));
```

But I get the error "MAX is not supported"

What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: While the FetchXML query is technically the correct answer, by using Order By, the LINQ query circumvents FetchXML's out-of-box limitations on Aggregates.  You could also do a similar non-aggregate query in FetchXML leveraging order by , with top="1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use fetchxml query & do a FetchExpression to fetch the result.

```xml
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
    <entity name='nychro_traportaldocumentupload'> 
       <attribute name='nychro_portaldocumentreviewid' alias='nychro_portaldocumentreviewid_max' aggregate='max' /> 
    </entity> 
</fetch>
```

Comment: Well, I think this would be the right answer, however I'd like to know how to execute this fetch in the right way from the AdxSutioPortal Code actually.

Comment: Look in this: https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/developers-guide/web-controls/crmdatasource/

Comment: For sure I'll mark it as good answer, however I haven't been able to retrieve the single expected value from inside adxstudioportal code. Outside Portalcode is quite simple, not the same inside.

Answer (score 3):

The following `linq` code, should be able to accomplish your requirement:

```
var documentno = (for a in XrmContext.CreateQuery("nychro_traportaldocumentupload")
                 orderby a.nychro_portaldocumentreviewid descending
                 select a).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does this bring all `nychro_traportaldocumentupload` recods into memory and then perform a `FirstOrDefault` or does this execute as a single statement on the server?

Comment: It does not load all records into memory. `FirstOrDefault` will lead to a `TOP 1` in the SQL.